# Why doesn't footer center with margin:0 auto?

Tags: html, css

Any ideas why the footer is not centering in the following code?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #container {width:1000px;margin:0 auto;}
            #footer {margin:0 auto;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

            <div>
                lksdfkjjindskfjsfkjflskfjsls.....sdlfkajsf
                sdfkjkkdiidkdkn   asdflkajf;lskdfioasfnasldf  ;lkjlthis is just a testing  
                ' sdlfk  sdlfk  dslfkjsf lskdfjsaf this elobrate   asdfkj   
                sdlfk  sldkfjsodsf lsdkfj   dlkjhgkjhgkjhg
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                copyright 2014
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WJw5H/

Comment: Because its `100%` width. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/WJw5H/1/)

Comment: Add `text-align: center` to the parent as a backup for `margin: 0 auto`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default a `div` is a block element. <s>This means it has `width: 100%;`</s>. `margin: 0 auto;` will center the element but how can it do that if its `width: 100%`.

For that matter!

*Actually it has `width: auto`, which for a block-level element is the full width of its container - but that's not 100% because otherwise padding would make it overflow* - **Niet the Dark Absol**

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/WJw5H/1/)

**CSS:**

```css
#footer { width: 200px; margin:0 auto;}
```

---

Also you could just `text-align: center;`

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/WJw5H/2/)

Comment: Actually it has `width: auto`, which for a block-level element is the full width of its container - but that's not `100%` because otherwise `padding` would make it overflow ;)

Comment: It isn't width 100%.  It's 1000px.

Comment: @4thSpace No the `#container` is `1000px`. Read  Niet the Dark Absol's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a `width` would resolve, but you would have to calculate the exact `width` for it, and when the footer changes, you will need to recalculate and update the `width` property as well.

A nice solution to that would be setting the `display` to `table`, so the width issue will automatically be resolved:

```
#footer {
    margin:0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/N65Nr/)

Comment: Nice solution for a dynamic width.

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer { text-align: center;  

   margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;

}
```

try this it will work perfect

copy this to the demo on http://jsfiddle.net/WJw5H/15/

```
<div id="container">

this is just a test.
</div>
<div id="footer">

copyright 2014

</div>

#container {width:1000px;margin:0 auto;}
#footer { text-align: center;  

   margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
```

Comment: `text-align: center;` has already been suggested by Ruddy. In the other hand, your former answer using the `<center>` tag would be an addition to the topic (even that I wouldn't suggest to use the `<center>` tag).

Comment: i try what was suggusted by Ruddy & didn't work for me until i add  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ; so i add this solution

Comment: You are right. Ruddy has editted his answer, adding the `text-align: center;` approach. Probably you have posted your answer before his additional edit. In that case, you have contributed with your edit. (see that you could still leave the `<center>` approach in your answer, and also note and keep in mind that in the `text-align: center;` approach, the `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` is not necessary).